# remove all character without specefic char from string?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, char

i have an input string , and i want to remove All char except special character(Hex Character) ! like this :

```
   String SpecialChar = "0123456789ABCDEF" ; // Hex Char 
   String input = "abdf%$%23%&373D^!Bfg(g)*a" ;
```

i want to have below output , but i get wrong value ...

```
   String output = "abdf23373DBfgga" ;
```

i write below method but it return wrong value :

```
private String EliminateExtra(String str) {
    String temp = str.toUpperCase(); 

    for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length() ; i++) {
        char c = temp.charAt(i);
        if(!isHexNum(c)) {
            temp = temp.replaceAll(String.valueOf(c) , "");
        }
    }
    return temp ;
}

private Boolean isHexNum(char c) {
    char[] charArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    for(int y=0 ; y<charArray.length ; y++) {
        if(charArray[y]==c) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

and call it like :

```
  String Data = "aaaDffagDDSGw!$!@$3513rX12433r1ADSfX&)&*)%(%8u4w" ;
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regex_textView1) ;
  tv.setText("Original:" + "\n" + Data.toUpperCase() + "\n" + "Result: " + "\n" + EliminateExtra(Data));
```

Comment: notice that when you change unwanted char to "" the length of you String is changing so your for loop may skip some chars

Comment: @hossein as Rafal said, your for-loop is not working logical because of temp is being modified in it. I made correct your loop at the below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use

```
private String EliminateExtra(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("[^a-fA-F0-9]","");
}
```

`replaceAll` uses regular expressions to find match and replace it with something else. In this case it will try to find all characters which are not in range described in [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^...]` and replace them with empty string (which means it removes them).

Comment: @Pshemo , i'm not new on Stack Overflow , i forgot to accept it !

Answer (score 1):

In your loop `for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length() ; i++)` you are modifying "temp" this causes that your loop is not working logical. I changed your for loop as;

```
private static String EliminateExtra(String str) {
    String temp = str.toUpperCase(); 
    String result = new String(); // create result string
    for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length() ; i++) {
        char c = temp.charAt(i);
        if(isHexNum(c)) {
            result += String.valueOf(c); // add valid char into your result string
        }
    }
    return result ;
}
```